# Disable autoindent in vim

Tags: vim, indentation

I use vim since almost 20 years and recently someone told me about the usage of = key for indenting a block of code. Sometimes I try a new vim key but stop using it because it isn't doing exactly what I want or I just don't need the feature. But in this case I find its a nice feature.

So I downloaded vim script 1120 (PHP-correct-Indenting) and installed it. My .vimrc contains:

```
filetype indent on
set smartindent
```

Now I can use = to indent a visually marked code block.

But I do NOT want vim to automatically indent code while I am typing. This is just irritating me as I am usually doing indentation myself and I am very much used to it ...

So how can I stop vim from automatically indenting my code while typing but can still continue to use = for indenting a visually marked block of text.

PS: Use hjkl for moving around in vim. It will make you about 1.5 times faster :)

My complete vimrc:

```
syntax on

set tabstop=3
set shiftwidth=3

execute pathogen#infect()

filetype indent on
set smartindent
```

Commenting the last two lines stops autoindenting but also using "=" does not use the mentioned vim script anymore

Comment: did you try `set noautoindent` or `set noai` for short?

Comment: PPS: Not using auto indentation makes you about 1.5 times slower! ;)

Answer (score 2):

The plugin sets `'indentexpr'`, which controls both explicit reindenting via `=` as well as indenting-as-you-type. Fortunately, you can control the triggering of the latter via the `'indentkeys'` option, so clearing that should work.

Put the following into `~/.vim/after/indent/php.vim`; this way, it'll apply *after* the plugin:

```
setlocal indentkeys=
```

Comment: Your suggestion works. But only when typed in normal mode while editing a file and then only for the currently edited file. Any suggestion how I make this work by default without changing the plugin?

Comment: Check `:scriptnames` whether the mentioned after file is actually sourced. You need `:filetype plugin on` for this; most people set this.

Answer (score 1):

The effect I want can get achieved using:

```
:set paste
```

This is exactly(?) the mode I wanted to switch into. No autoindenting at all. But the "=" key works to indent a marked block of text.

Maybe I will add "set paste" to my .vimrc :)

Thanks for your support anyways.

Comment: `paste` also turns off several other features.  This is not a general-purpose solution.